# RestSharp Post a JSON Object

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

I am trying to post the following JSON with RestSharp:

```
{"UserName":"UAT1206252627",
"SecurityQuestion":{
    "Id":"Q03",
    "Answer":"Business",
    "Hint":"The answer is Business"
},
}
```

I think that I am close, but I seem to be struggling with the **SecurityQuestion** (the API is throwing an error saying a parameter is missing, but it doesn't say which one)

This is the code I have so far:

```
var request = new RestRequest("api/register", Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

request.AddParameter("UserName", "UAT1206252627");

SecurityQuestion securityQuestion = new SecurityQuestion("Q03");
request.AddParameter("SecurityQuestion", request.JsonSerializer.Serialize(securityQuestion));

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

And my Security Question class looks like this:

```
public class SecurityQuestion
{
    public string id {get; set;}
    public string answer {get; set;}
    public string hint {get; set;}

    public SecurityQuestion(string id)
    {
         this.id = id;
         answer = "Business";
         hint = "The answer is Business";
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Is there any other way to post the Security Question object ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You need to specify the content-type in the header:

```
request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

Also `AddParameter` adds to POST or URL querystring based on Method

I think you need to add it to the body like this:

```
request.AddJsonBody(
    new 
    {
      UserName = "UAT1206252627", 
      SecurityQuestion = securityQuestion
    }); // AddJsonBody serializes the object automatically
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Oluwafemi, but I am still getting the same error (that a parameter is missing) - I know it seems like this should work, but is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Can you give a sample method of the APl?

Comment: It does work for me:

request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
request.AddJsonBody(yourobject);

Comment: Thank you for your solution

Comment: Really doesn't work. Correct approach is: `r.AddParameter("application/json", JsonSerializerHelper.Serialize(keys), ParameterType.RequestBody);`

Comment: I am passing an array and gets a response `"StatusCode: NotFound, Content-Type: , Content-Length: 0)"`

here's what I did:
request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            request.AddJsonBody(branchCode);

Comment: Don't forget to use @ with reserved words, for example `request.AddJsonBody(new { @event = "view" });`

Answer (score 28):

Thanks again for your help. To get this working I had to submit everything as a single parameter. This is the code I used in the end.

First I made a couple of classes called Request Object and Security Question:

```
public class SecurityQuestion
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public string Hint { get; set; }
}

public class RequestObject
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public SecurityQuestion SecurityQuestion { get; set; }
}
```

Then I just added it as a single parameter, and serialized it to JSON before posting it, like so:

```
var yourobject = new RequestObject
            {
                UserName = "UAT1206252627",
                SecurityQuestion = new SecurityQuestion
                {
                    Id = "Q03",
                    Answer = "Business",
                    Hint = "The answer is Business"
                },
            };
var json = request.JsonSerializer.Serialize(yourobject);

request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

and it worked !

Answer (score 11):

To post raw json body string, AddBody(), or AddJsonBody() methods will not work. Use the following instead

```
request.AddParameter(
   "application/json",
   "{ \"username\": \"johndoe\", \"password\": \"secretpassword\" }", // <- your JSON string
   ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Comment: Yes, the raw approach is many times useful, for example, when passing in a body that is stored in a database

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the easiest way to do this is to let RestSharp handle all of the serialization.  You just need to specify the RequestFormat like so.  Here's what I came up with for what I'm working on.  .

```
    public List<YourReturnType> Get(RestRequest request)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest
        {
            Resource = "YourResource",
            RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json,
            Method = Method.POST
        };
        request.AddBody(new YourRequestType());

        var response = Execute<List<YourReturnType>>(request);
        return response.Data;
    }

    public T Execute<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
    {
        var client = new RestClient(_baseUrl);

        var response = client.Execute<T>(request);
        return response.Data;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`RestSharp` supported from object by `AddObject` method

```
request.AddObject(securityQuestion);
```