# Send JSON array with RestSharp

Tags: c#, restsharp

I want to send this JSON string with RestSharp as a parameter:

```
{"filter":[{"date_modified":{"$dateBetween":["2017-10-13","2017-10-13"]}}]}
```

Ideally I'd like to do something like this:

```
request.AddParameter("filter","[{"date_modified":{"$dateBetween":["2017-10-13","2017-10-13"]}}]");
```

But does obviously not work. But how can I solve it?

Edit:
I have tried sending in the json string through a REST client so I know it works.

Regards,
Erik

Comment: does not work because...? You didn't say what the error is. But I guess maybe the internal quote marks? You can escape them with a backslash.

Comment: The api does not recognice it. Which leads me to believe it is not serializing it correctly. I have tried the backslashes but it produces the same result.

Comment: The code you provide cannot compile because you do not escape the `"`

Comment: Have you considered adding the json to the body rather than passing it as a parameter in the url? Perhaps this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31937939/restsharp-post-a-json-object has some information you can use.

Comment: Deblaton: I wrote this on the fly in the post. But the backslashes are there in the actual code.

Comment: @kkirk I tried doing that but then the api just ignored it.

Comment: @Erik How are you trying to read the body in the API? Have you tried something like await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() or using the [FromBody] attribute on a method parameter to get the body? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm working with SugarCRMs API so that part I can't really affect I'm afraid.

Comment: I know there are issues with handling collections when using the default serialiser. Consider using JSON.NET serialiser, there is a separate package for this. We will add it to the core repository later.