# C# RestSharp AddJsonBody() doesn't add API call Body name

Tags: c#, json.net, restsharp, rest

I am working with RestSharp and an API I believe is set up with Azure. I making a POST request to the API, but have noted that the request only works when the **body is named, "agentGetRequest" in Postman**.
Bad Body:

```json
{
    "supplierKey": "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX",
    "inputDate": "2021-01-17T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```

Good Body:

```json
{
"agentGetRequest": {
    "supplierKey": "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX",
    "inputDate": "2021-01-17T00:00:00.000Z"
}
}
```

So when I run my code

```cs
void Post(AgentRequest agentRequest, Credentials creds )
{
    Uri baseUrl = new Uri(creds.baseURL);
    IRestClient client = new RestClient(baseUrl);

    IRestRequest request = new RestRequest(ENDPOINT, Method.POST);

    request.AddHeader("subscriptionKey", creds.subscriptionKey);
    // Option 1:
    request.AddJsonBody(agentRequest);
    // Option 2:
    request.AddJsonBody(agentRequest, "agentGetRequest")

    IRestResponse<GetAgentResponse> response = client.Execute<GetAgentResponse>(request);

    if (response.IsSuccessful)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response.Content));
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(response.ErrorMessage);
    }
}

// Body request object
public class AgentRequest 
{
    public string inputDate { get; set; }
    public string supplierKey { get; set; }
}
```

It throws a bad request error because it can't find the body, "agentRequest."

I have found a workaround where I feed it a string as the body - but this would hate to have to do this for every endpoint:

```cs
// Instead of request.AddJsonBody()...
string body = "{\"agentGetRequest\": {\"supplierKey\": \"XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX\",\"inputDate\": \"2021-0117T00:00:00.000Z\"}}";

request.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

How can I correctly format the body when adding it via AddJsonBody to include the name (and maybe the encapsulating brackets)?

Comment: Check out RestSharp Post a JSON Object's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31938886/1360389). The "name" you want can be also a part of the JSON structure, which means a property of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recording to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31938886/1360389) of RestSharp Post a JSON Object, you could add JSON body like below:

```
request.AddJsonBody(
new 
{
  agentGetRequest = agentRequest
}); // AddJsonBody serializes the object automatically
```

Comment: You are totally right, I didn't realize that would format the body correctly.